# Internet connected but not working

Tags: boot, internet, connection

I've been spending the past week setting up Ubuntu, and I've encountered a bit of a roadblock; for some reason, the past few days my internet's been connected, but nothing's loading. 
When I reboot, it works for a few minutes, then suddenly stops, and can't be reset through all my attempts.

Also, when I boot up, I get a message of 'input not supported' with the rest of my screen blacked out. I was wondering if there's any way to fix that...
Thanks for taking the time to read through my concerns.

Comment: Sorry for being vague; I'm too used to being able to ask people I know for tech help. Anyways, it's wireless, and it works perfectly after restart, for a few minutes. It's not the ISP either, because two other computers in the same household are connected constantly. This computer was alsI connected whilst I was using WinXP OS.

Comment: You should probably ask a separate question about the 'input not supported' error.  You're unlikely to get an answer for it tacked onto the wifi question

Answer (score 0):

I think to properly answer this a little more information may be needed. When you say "connected" does that mean wifi or wired??

Assuming that means a physical cable is plugged in then here's a quick list.

1. Check your ethernet cable from the switch/router/modem to your computer. Validate that there is actually a link being established. Possibly even reset your modem
2. Next Open Network Manager and navigate down to "Connection Information"

   Take note of what your IPv4 address is. The most commonly used class C address from your consumer router/modem is:

   **192.168.X.X**

   Take a look at your Broadcast Address and Default Route as well. If your network was properly configured then all of those entries would be populated, most likely they will be of the same range of numbers as your IP Address. If any of these entries don't appear then that may be your problem.

   Next follow this [Guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=25557) on the Ubuntu Forum and perhaps ask your question in the forum. I have only giving a fraction of what the troubleshooting will consist of and the community may be able to better answer you there. This way you can submit your debug logs,etc.